# How to get smooth bevel edges with smart bevel operation

Tags: mesh, modifiers

I'm trying to perform smart bevel on a cube, but I can't get the edges to be smooth. The cube and sphere have almost the same faces so the Boolean operation doesn't get all messy. What's the correct method to get this type of shape clean with good topology?

[image]

Comment: does it have to be non-destructive or can you rework the topology?

Comment: I'm open to suggestions to get a clean result.  I know it's only 2 objects, but it's giving me grief trying to make it look correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to stay non-destructive, use a 16/8 sphere as an boolean object, make sure that its center is at the exact same position as the cube vertex, and use the following modifiers: *Boolean (Fast)/Bevel/Subdivision (Level > 4)*:

[image]

If you work destructively you just need to apply the *Boolean* and create some bevels manually:

[image]

To have a better topology, just join these vertices:

[image]

Comment: OK, great, thanks for this.